# Minimum questions to guess number between $1-1$ million

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Suppose Alice can pick a number in $\{1,...,1000000\}$. Bob is allowed to ask yes/no questions, Alice is allowed to lie once.

What's the minimum number of questions Bob has to ask to guarantee that he correctly finds the number.

---

I thought about a Hamming code (can correct up to $1$ error) that has enough data bits to store $10^6$. Unfortunately, the smallest Hamming code that fits that criteria is $(31,26)$, which can encode the first $2^{26}=67108864$ natural numbers. That's a lot more than a million.

So I was wondering if $31$ questions are indeed the smallest number of questions to solve the problem or if there is another method/code that requires less questions.

Comment: How did you come up with $(31, 26)$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog because $(15,11)$ doesn't fit the problem and the next "bigger" Hamming code is $(31,26)$, isn't it?

Comment: @OscarLanzi It seem's like you're assuming that Alice never lies?

Comment: Missed that, never mind.

Comment: @OscarLanzi No worries!

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see now. Hamming codes are perfect codes, but one could create an imperfect code that fits the size of the problem better. I believe the minimum size here is $(25,20)$, though I don't know how to construct it or even if it would be linear.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Sounds good to me. $20$ would fit perfectly. Do you think I could implement the same logic for the parity bits as for $(31,26)$ but only for the first $20$ digits instead of the $26$?

Answer (score 4):

This is called Ulam's game, or *searching with lies*. There is quite a bit of literature, as well as a survey paper by Pelc available [here](https://www.gwern.net/docs/statistics/comparison/2002-pelc.pdf).

For the case of exactly one lie, $e=1,$ Pelc has proved that the minimum length of the questioner's strategy is
$$
\min\{n: M(n+1)\leq 2^n\},
$$
for $M$ even. Here $M$ is one million which gives $n=25$ as the required length. The above expression is just a version of the Hamming volume bound for existence of an $e$ error correcting code, namely
$$
M\sum_{i=0}^e \binom{n}{i}\leq 2^n.
$$

See page 80 of the linked paper for reference [91] where an explicit strategy is apparently given, also by Pelc, in the form of an adaptive search.

Comment: Didn't want to impose my own edit on what looks like a typo.  Looks like you want `\binom{n}{i}` instead of `\binomialni`.